# How to fix SoundCloud player since API updates?

Tags: javascript, api, soundcloud

I've been working with this code that builds a custom SoundCloud player from hrefs to the tracks via their API:

https://codepen.io/nicholaspetersen/pen/yyVYMY

It was working fine until SoundCloud changed the way their API authorises as described here:

https://developers.soundcloud.com/blog/security-updates-api

They said in that post:

*Currently, to access the public resources of the platform, server-side integrations with our API only require a `client_id` in the URL’s query parameter. We’ll be strengthening our authorization here by making all public resources on the API only accessible to apps that have been authorized with the `client_credentials` grant. This will enable the app to capture both the `access_token` and the `refresh_token` to then fetch the resources from the API. **Please note that the use of `client_id` will be deprecated and deleted soon (from July 2021). Developers should provide the `Authentication` header for all their requests to the SoundCloud API going forward***.*

So, my understanding from the above is that I need to update the `Authentication` header as currently the code above is authenticating using this code:

```
// convert a SoundCloud resource URL to an API URL
      scApiUrl = function(url, apiKey) {
        var resolver = ( secureDocument || (/^https/i).test(url) ? 'https' : 'http') + '://api.' + domain + '/resolve?url=',
            params = 'format=json&consumer_key=' + apiKey +'&callback=?';
```

However, I'm completely stuck as to how to do that... can anyone take a look at the JS in that codepen and let me know what I should be doing to fix the issue? I thought it might involve updating the code above to include a `callback` URL, but then that blog post says the use of `client_id` is now deprecated.

Any help / pointers hugely welcome.

Comment: Literally no one here helps with SoundCloud issues, not even the developers at SoundCloud respond. It's incredible.

Comment: I am having a similar issue, my app fetches the playlist like 1/5 times now. It's so hard to understand the procedure enumerated in the improved security document FFS.  Hopefully, someone will help us :/

Comment: Same here, I'll have to manually edit the SoundCloud module/package I'm using to add the Auth header in the request...

Answer (score 1):

After the SoundCloud security updates, the playlist on my website also stopped working. It wouldn't load any of the tracks in my playlist. I did a lot of research, finally realizing that I would need to register an app on SoundCloud to get access to the API. This was not possible due to the app registration page being down since early this year and with no promises of it ever going back up. So, I needed to find an alternative. Which brought me to the Widget API page.

https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/html5-widget

The Widget API allows you to externally control the widget that is embedded on your website through javascript. You set the width and height of the widget to 0 and it hides the widget. I tinkered with this on codepen this week and I am pleased that I now have a working playlist ready to be utilized on my website. See the link below.

https://codepen.io/mdcrowcodes/pen/eYEMyzY

```
enter code here
```

Comment: Good to know that widget api is still working,  I am gonna try to build a npm package for it.